# boxplot of weekends vs weekdays data in python

Tags: python, boxplot

I have energy consumption daily data. I want to plot a boxplot of energy consumption on weekends vs energy consumption on weekdays.

The data is similar to this:

| date | Energy |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-01-08 | 13.690 |
| 2018-01-09 | 5.400 |
| 2018-01-10 | 28.859 |
| 2018-01-11 | 16.132 |
| 2018-01-12 | 15.233 |
| 2018-01-15 | 0.000 |
| 2018-01-16 | 0.000 |
| 2018-01-17 | 20.234 |
| 2018-01-18 | 42.416 |
| 2018-01-19 | 12.956 |
| 2018-01-22 | 17.412 |
| 2018-01-23 | 11.378 |
| 2018-01-24 | 20.749 |
| 2018-01-25 | 18.997 |
| 2018-01-26 | 31.387 |
| 2018-01-29 | 15.025 |
| 2018-01-30 | 20.141 |
| 2018-01-31 | 18.758 |
| 2018-02-01 | 16.275 |
| 2018-02-02 | 6.358 |

and the boxplot should be similar to this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Update- this is what I tried:

I tried to create a column with weekdays and another column with weekends so that then I can plot them in the boxplot.

```
data.set_index('real date', inplace= True)
data.index.name = 'date'
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

data["weekday"]=data.apply(lambda row: row["date"].weekday(),axis=1)
data["weekend"] = (data["weekday"] < 5).astype(int)
```

### The keyError is from the third line.

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'date'

Comment: `data.apply(lambda row: row["date"].weekday(),axis=1)` Isn't it necessary to modify `row.index.weekday()`, since the date column is specified as the index before this line?

Comment: If the error is gone, the following code should be able to draw the graph. `data['year'] = data['date'].dt.year;import seaborn as sns;sns.boxplot(data=data,x='year', y='value', hue='weekend')`

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could take a look at matplotlib or plotly.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I was able to solve my own problem:

Beware that I dropped the date as index. "date" is now a column that's why I wrote: `data["date"]`

```
dic={0:'Weekend',1:'Weekday'}
data['month'] = data["date"].dt.strftime('%b,%Y')
data['day'] = data.weekday.map(dic)
a=plt.figure(figsize=(18,4)) 
plt1=sns.boxplot('month','Energy',hue='day',width=0.6,fliersize=3,
                    data=data_d)
```

This blog was of great help: https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-analysis-visualization-forecasting-with-lstm-77a905180eba